# C++0x issue: Constant time insertion into std::set

Tags: c++, stl, insert, set, complexity-theory

According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/insert/), I can achieve constant time insertion if I use

```
iterator std::set::insert ( iterator position, const value_type& x );
```

and the `position` iterator I provide directly "precedes" the proper (in-order) insertion point.

Now the case I'm concerned with is if I know that the value I'm inserting goes at the end (since it's the largest), e.g.:

```
set<int> foo = {1, 2, 3};
foo.insert(4); // this is an inefficient insert
```

According to the above criterion I should pass the last element `foo.end()-1` to `insert` **not** `foo.end()`. Is my understanding correct? What happens if I pass `foo.end()`? Will it be a `O(log n)` insertion or a `O(1)` one. So, the options are:

```
// Option A
foo.insert(foo.end()-1, 4);

// Option B
foo.insert(foo.end(), 4);

// Safer version of Option A
if(foo.empty())
    foo.insert(4);
else
    foo.insert(foo.end()-1, 4);
```

I ask because I'm writing a function that's templated on the container. I want to insert an element (that I know is the largest) to the end of whatever container is passed in. Using "Option A" above has a different behavior for a container like `vector`:

```
foo.insert(foo.end()-1, 4);
// result is {1, 2, 3, 4} if foo is an std::set
// result is {1, 2, 4, 3} if foo is an std::vector
```

As @Bo_Persson suggests, the problem here is that C++03 says "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if t is inserted right after p." while C++0x says "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if t is inserted right before p."

PS: I'm using GCC 4.5 on Ubuntu 11.04 with C++0x support enabled.

Edit: I ran empirical tests with C++0x support enabled and disabled and [posted the results in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562686/c0x-issue-constant-time-insertion-into-stdset/6566247#6566247). Basically, the conclusion is that it's just as good (and is obviously safer) to provide `end()` as the insertion hint. However, that's obviously just an empirical observation. The standard, as stated, is still confusing on this aspect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it cheating to run a test instead of reading through library specifications?

For `g++-4.4 -O2` for the integers `0 <= i < 5000000` my running times for 
standard insertion are

```
real    0m14.952s
user    0m14.665s
sys 0m0.268s
```

and my running times for insertion using `end()` as hint are

```
real    0m4.373s
user    0m4.148s
sys 0m0.224s
```

Insertion at `end() - 1` is just as fast as far as I can tell, but it is more cumbersome to use because `end() - 1` is an illegal operation (you have to use `operator--()`) and it crashes if the set happens to be empty.

```
#include <set>

typedef std::set<int> Set;

void insert_standard(Set& xs, int x)
{
    xs.insert(x);
}

void insert_hint_end(Set& xs, int x)
{
    xs.insert(xs.end(), x);
}

int main()
{
    const int cnt = 5000000;
    Set xs;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        // insert_hint_end(xs, i);
        insert_standard(xs, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great test. I'm assuming that's with C++0x support **not** enabled.

Answer (score 3):

It is not totally clear if the `position` should be pointing before or after the insertion point. Some implementations work with either.

On the other hand, if you want different behavior for different containers, why don't you just write two overloads for your function, one for containers with a `push_back` function and one for `std::set`.

Comment: It'd be nice to check a couple of current implementations to see how this is handles. I believe that GCC had a change where they went from "checking a couple of neighbouring values" to checking only the hint and then aborting. But since `end()` can't be evaluated, I would hazard a guess that it can be used to successfully hint insertion of an element that's larger than all existing ones; it'd be a sensible and easy thing to implement.

Comment: A problem here is that C++03 says "logarithmic in general, but
amortized constant if t is inserted right **after** p." while C++0x says "logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if t is inserted right **before** p." What should a poor compiler do? :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: I would rather say, what should a poor library writer do ? And it seems "obvious" that he should follow the standard for which he codes, ie use C++0x standard for the C++0x flavor of the library (the one with `emplace*` methods and all). I think this change originated in order to accomodate the `end()` case more easily.

Comment: @Matthieu - But that means breaking old code, which is not nice. I think the change might be caused by a new C++0x requirement for multiset/map to keep equivalent nodes in insert order.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Note that you are not breaking the semantics of the code, but only the "performance" aspect. Your guess seem better than mine, since there was no guarantee before.

Comment: I wonder if `end()` could be treated as a special case. So if you pass in `end()` the performance will be the same as if you passed in `end()-1`. This I think is reasonable and remains valid under both the old and the new standard.

Comment: The C++0x version fixes `set<int> foo = {1, 2, 3}; foo.insert(some_iterator, 0)` by making it actually be possible to use `foo.begin()` as `some_iterator`?

Comment: GCC 4.6 refers to [this documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt07ch17.html).

Comment: @Kerrek, yep, but that's GCC without C++0x enabled I'm guessing (not that it would be different, but I'm just saying). I think the new C++0x standard has slightly different wording, as @Bo explains. I hope that the three cases in the document you link will remain as is.

Answer (score 2):

Only supplying an iterator that falls immediately *after* the new value makes any sense.

That's because in a collection of N elements, there are N+1 possible insertion points.  An iterator exists that comes *after* a value higher than any preexisting element, but *there is no iterator that comes before a value before all elements*.

Comment: I haven't thought of that. That's a great way of putting it. The standard for `std::set` should reflect this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Following in the footsteps of @antonakos, I'm expanding on the "cheating" solution and running an empirical test. I'm using GCC 4.5 with optimization (`-02`) and considering both the case when C++0x support is not enabled and when it is with `-std=c++0x`. Results on 40,000,000 insertions are as follows (showing system time as the other values in this case are not special):

- Without C++0x support

  - No hint: 26.6 seconds
  - Hint at `end()`: **5.71 seconds**
  - Hint at `--end()`: 5.84 seconds
- With C++0x support enabled

  - No hint: 29.2 seconds
  - Hint at `end()`: **5.34 seconds**
  - Hint at `--end()`: 5.54 seconds

**Conclusion**: GCC (with or without C++0x enabled) inserts efficiently when `end()` is provided as the insertion hint.

The code I used is based on @antonakos's:

```
#include <set>
typedef std::set<int> Set;

void insert_standard(Set & xs, int x) {
    xs.insert(x);
}

void insert_hint_end(Set & xs, int x) {
    xs.insert(xs.end(), x);
}

void insert_hint_one_before_end(Set & xs, int x) {
    xs.insert(--xs.end(), x);
}

int main() {
    const int cnt = 40000000;
    Set xs;
    xs.insert(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < cnt; i++) {
        //insert_standard(xs, i);
        //insert_hint_one_before_end(xs, i);
        insert_hint_end(xs, i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```